# convert for loop to apply function in python to reduce run-time

Tags: python, function, dataframe, for-loop

I have a for-loop looks like this, but it takes a long time to run once a large dataset being passed into it.

```
for i in range(0,len(data_sim.index)):
    for j in range(1,len(data_sim.columns)):
        user = data_sim.index[i]
        activity = data_sim.columns[j]

        if dt_full.loc[i][j] != 0: 
            data_sim.loc[i][j] = 0
        else:
            activity_top_names = data_neighbours.loc[activity][1:dt_length]
            activity_top_sims = data_corr.loc[activity].sort_values(ascending=False)[1:dt_length]
            user_purchases = data_activity.loc[user,activity_top_names]

            data_sim.loc[i][j] = getScore(user_purchases,activity_top_sims)
```

In for-loop, data_sim looks like this:

```
CustomerId     A      B      C     D      E
   1          NAs   NAs    NAs   NAs    NAs
   2           ..
```

I tried to reproduce the same process in apply function, which looks like this:

```
def test(cell):

    user = cell.index
    activity = cell

    activity_top_names = data_neighbours.loc[activity][1:dt_length]
    activity_top_sims = data_corr.loc[activity].sort_values(ascending=False)[1:dt_length]
    user_purchase = data_activity_index.loc[user, activity_top_names]

    if dt_full.loc[user][activity] != 0:
        return cell.replace(cell, 0)

    else:
        re = getScore(user_purchase, activity_top_sims) 
        return cell.replace(cell, re)
```

In function, data_sim2 looks like this, I set the 'CustomerId' column to index column and duplicated the activity name to each activity column.

```
CustomerId(Index)     A      B      C     D      E
   1                  A      B      C     D      E
   2                  A      B      C     D      E
```

Inside of the function 'def test(cell)', if the cell is in data_sim2[1][0],

```
cell.index = 1  # userId
cell            # activity name
```

The whole idea of this for-loop is to fit the scoring data into 'data_sim' table based on position of each cell. And I used the same idea in creating function, used the same calculation in each cell, then apply this to the data table 'data_sim',

```
data_test = data_sim2.apply(lambda x: test(x))
```

it gave me a error said

```
"sort_values() missing 1 required positional argument: 'by'"
```

which is odd, because this issue was not happening inside of for loop. It sounds like the 'data_corr.loc[activity]' is still a Dataframe istead of a Series.

Comment: What is `c` in the second snippet? I can see it used as an index, but you never declare it. Did you mean `cell`, or `activity`?

Comment: In function, cell means each cell in the dataframe, the cell.index refer to the user Id, the cell itself is the name of activity. In for-loop, it used [i][j] is locate where the cell is.

Comment: Fine, but I asked what `c` is. I can't see it declared in the code you posted.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. it means activity.